# How to recover ALSA default configuration after reverting changes in .asoundrc?

Tags: audio, alsa

I've done some changes via `.asoundrc` (created "softvol" volume controls).

Now, I want to get rid of these changes. Nothing of the following helped so far:

- Deleted `.asoundrc` and rebooted system.
- Created empty `.asoundrc`
- `alsactl` commands (`restore`, `init`, ...)
- Temporarily removed `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state`
- ...

**Any ideas on how to get back to the original config and have the volume controls I added vanish from `alsamixer`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `softvol` controls are stored in memory together with other data related to the actual sound card, and are saved to and restored from `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` when the machine is shutting down or booting.

So to remove them, you have to

1. unload the sound driver module (`rmmod snd-hda-intel`, or whatever you're using), and then
2. remove the entry from `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` (or the entire file).